# ValueError: Cannot convert string from Entry to int even though input is int

Tags: python, tkinter

The Entry self.r has input of '1,12', and I'm trying to convert it to a tuple of (1,12). The method:
        tup = tuple(int(x) for x in self.r.split(",")) works for normal python program, but when used with input from Entry, it gives this Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/LazyLinh/PycharmProjects/TimeGenGUI/GUI/__init__.py", line 54, in calculateTime
tup = tuple(int(x) for x in self.r.split(","))
  File "/Users/LazyLinh/PycharmProjects/TimeGenGUI/GUI/__init__.py", line 54, in <genexpr>
tup = tuple(int(x) for x in self.r.split(","))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

What could the issue be? This is my full code:

```
from tkinter import *
import math

class TimeGenerator:

    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.grid()
        label_iso = Label(root, text="Isotope A, Element")
        label_vol = Label(root, text="Voltage")
        label_range = Label(root, text="Charge Range")

        entry_iso = Entry(root)
        entry_vol = Entry(root)
        entry_range = Entry(root)

        label_iso.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        label_vol.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        label_range.grid(row=2, sticky=E)

        entry_iso.grid(row=0, column=1)
        entry_vol.grid(row=1, column=1)
        entry_range.grid(row=2,column=1)

        button = Button(root, text='Time Range', command=self.calculateTime)
        button.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)


        self.iso = entry_iso.get()
        self.vol = entry_vol.get()
        self.r = entry_range.get()

    def calculateTime(self):
        x = 5

        self.iso.replace(" ", "")
        list = []
        for e in self.iso.split(","):
            list.append(e)

        f = open("/Users/LazyLinh/PycharmProjects/mass.mas12.txt", "r")
        i = 0
        while (i < 40):
            header = f.readline()
            i += 1

        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            columns = line.split()
            if (list[0] == columns[5]):
                if (list[1] == columns[6]):
                    self.mass = float(columns[13]) + float(columns[14])

        self.r.replace(" ", "")
        tup = tuple(int(x) for x in self.r.split(","))

        list = []
        for q in range(tup[0], tup[1] + 1):
            y = x * math.sqrt(self.mass / (2 * q * float(self.vol)))
            list.append(y)
        i = tup[0]
        for time in list:
            print(i, ':', time)
            i = i + 1


root = Tk()
b = TimeGenerator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Before the offending line, print out `self.r`. Does it end or start with a comma or contain two consecutive ones?

Comment: A split will return you tokens type string and if that string is not a valid integer , it can result in such errors. So i think you are probably getting a token (after split) which is a blank space(not a valid string), this error.

Comment: You are getting the contents of the Entry immediately (in "_ _init__") before anything has been entered, You want to get the value in self.calculateTime i.e. after something has been entered.

Comment: "the entry `self.r`" well no `self.r` is a string, not the entry.  You need to save a reference to `entry_iso` and get the contents inside the `calculateTime` method.

Comment: look at the error message: it's telling you it's trying to convert an empty string. That's a useful clue.

Comment: I'm a newbie to python, so all of your comments helped, thank you!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a 'gotcha' that I have seen before, where you expect this:

```
self.r = entry_range.get()
```

To say "let `self.r` be the string value of the entry" but it is actually "let `self.r` be the *current* content of the entry" as in when you use `self.r` later it still represents the value immediately after initialization (where you called `.get()`) which is always `''`. (an empty string)

The solution is simply *get the content of the entry when you need it* so just have a reference to your entries instead of `get`ting then immediately:

```
    self.iso_entry = entry_iso
    self.vol_entry = entry_vol
    self.r_entry = entry_range
```

Then when you are going to use the value in the entry you use the `.get()` method:

```
iso = self.iso_entry.get().replace(" ", "")
#btw, try not to shadow the name 'list'
list = iso.split(",") #this returns a list, no extra work needed.
...
r = self.r_entry.get().replace(" ","")
tup = tuple(int(x) for x in r.split(","))
```

Another way is to instead use `properties` so that it **does** retrieve the current value of the entry every time you use `self.r`:

```
class TimeGenerator:
    @property
    def r(self):
        return self.r_entry.get()
    @property
    def iso(self):
        return self.iso_entry.get()
    @property
    def vol(self):
        return self.vol_entry.get()
```

Then you can leave the code as it is and using `self.r` will dynamically get the contents for you, although don't expect this to do anything noticeable:

```
self.r.replace(" ","")
```

Python strings are immutable so the `.replace` method returns a *new* string that you don't do anything with, if you wanted to change it you would normally do:

```
 self.r = self.r.replace(" ","")
```

But without having a `setter` for the property this raises an error, so you will probably end up using a local variable anyway:

```
r = self.r.replace(" ","")
tup = tuple(int(x) for x in r.split(","))
```