# Spinbox output value

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been working with `Tkinter` and I'm having a problem with `spinbox`. I have `spinbox` set to: `from_=1, to=5`. No mater what I do `spinbox` outputs a 5 as it's variable. I've read lot's of post here on other's answer for related questions and can't seem to find an answer.

Clicking the mouse and selecting a value in the `spinbox` does nothing.

Here is the code :

```
sp1=Spinbox(root, bd=3, state='readonly', from_=1, to=5, font="bold", wrap="true")
sp1.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=20)
sp1.delete(0, END)
sp1.bind("<Button-1>")
i=sp1.get()
```

`i` is always equal to 5.

Comment: the value of `l` is not going to ever change, you need to `.get()` the value of the slider when you need to use the value. (that is why it is called `.get()`)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215397/valueerror-cannot-convert-string-from-entry-to-int-even-though-input-is-int/37216659#37216659 although I'm sure there is a better example I could point you to.

Comment: you want something more like this ? http://pastebin.com/dH37xGmG

Comment: @PaulRooney you could put this code as answer.

Comment: true but I'm not sure its what the OP wants. Not wanting to jump the gun. I will if he asks me to.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign function to `Spinbox` using `command=` and this function will be executed everytime you change value in `Spinbox`. And then you can get value from `Spinbox`. Now you get value only at start.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def callback():
    print("value:", w.get())

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

w = tk.Spinbox(root, state='readonly', from_=1, to=5, command=callback)
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callback function to the `command` argument when you initialize the `Spinbox`:

```
# python 3
from tkinter import *
# python 2
#from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def on_spinbox_change():
    print(sp1.get())

sp1 = Spinbox(root, bd=3, state='readonly', from_=1, to=5, font="bold", wrap="true", command=on_spinbox_change)
sp1.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=20)

root.mainloop()
```